# how to access json data with special character in key in json in angular js

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to access data with key name as
[Measure].[item0] as the key names and when i access this in my html it gives error 
like json is ine format "[Measure].[item0]":"45"
my code for accessing this is

```
<div ng-repeat="item in allItems ">
      <div >{{item.([Measures].[Item0])}}</div>
</div>
```

I have tried this using braces and paranthesis also byenclosing it in () and []
i just want to know that how to access the key name with full stop

Comment: Have you tried `{{ item["[Measures].[Item0]"] }}`?

Comment: @bmleite yeah thanx it worked, you can post it as answer might help some other too.

Comment: Just accept @EdHinchliffe answer, it's more complete than mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not particularly clear what you are trying to do from the question, but if you have an object like this:

```
{
  item: {
    "[Measures].[Item0]": "some data",
    someProperty        : 31231
  }
}
```

Then to output `"some data"` the expression would be like this:

```
{{item["[Measures].[Item0]"]}}
```

If your item looks like this:

```
{
  item: {
    Measures: {
      Item0: "some data",
      Item1: "some other data"
    },
    someProperty        : 31231
  }
}
```

Then your html for `"some data"` should be

```
{{item.Measures.Item0}}
```

In other words:

```
{{ item.key === item["key"] }}
```

The square bracket notation can contain restricted/special characters, whilst the dot notation cannot. To be quite honest, you should fix the data source if it looks like the first, it's really not good practise.